# Can I use other HLS players on CAF receiver?

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

I would like to continue using most of what the CAF receiver handles for me, like reporting playback state to the sender, etc. However, I would like to sometimes (and I really mean only sometimes) use `hls.js` instead of whatever HLS player the CAF receiver uses.

The reason I want to do this is that there are some videos I've tested that doesn't work with the normal CAF receiver but work fine with `hls.js` on the Chromecast. I have even filed a [bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/139175785) but haven't heard anything about it.

Does anyone know how to do this?